# Determine which statement failed in multiple-line try

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible, in Python 2.7, to do something like this:

```
try:
   -command A-
   -command B-
   -command C-
except ...:
   print("The exception occured during command " + failedCmd)
```

In other words, is there a way to know which statement failed in a multiple-line try block, rather than seperating it to 3 different, one-line try blocks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way using the `traceback` module which extracts traceback information:

```
import traceback
import sys

try:
    def func():
        raise TypeError:
    func()
except TypeError:
    e = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print(traceback.extract_tb(e)[0][3])
```

Which prints

```
func()
```

Have a look at the full output of `traceback.extract_tb(e)` as it gives a list of tuples for each level in the call stack. Each one contains `(file, line_no, module_or_func, line_text)` and you may want to change which values you use. In the example, I used the line_text from the bottom of the stack (first thing to be called).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sys` to get line number where exception was thrown:

```
import sys

try:
    a = 1/2
    b = 2/0
    c = 3/-1
except Exception as e:
    trace_back = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print("Exception in line {}".format(trace_back.tb_lineno), e)

# Exception in line 5 division by zero
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I need to specify the name of the command to the user, rather than the line #?

Comment: @RazMoshe, I don't think there is a way you can get the program to return what command failed; atmost what you get is the line # so you know what command failed. (my understanding). If there is anything more, I would be also interested. ;)

Comment: @Austin After a look at `sys.exc_info` in the docs, it led me to the `traceback` module which does have this feature. See my answer below - I certainly learnt something new!

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    failedCmd = 'A'
    1/10 # -command A-
    failedCmd = 'B'
    1/0 # -command B-
    failedCmd = 'C'
    1*0 # -command C-
    failedCmd = ''
except:
   print("The exception occured during command " + failedCmd)
```

**Output**

```
The exception occured during command B
```

Comment: Thanks, but I thought maybe there's a built-in mechanism to handle this case...?
Your solution works great, but there's a significant code-line redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having multiple `except` clauses, *and* get both the line number and the function name where the failure occurred, *and* get useful information about why the command failed, like this:

```
import traceback

try:
   -command A-
   -command B-
   -command C-
except ...:
   print("The exception occurred as shown in the traceback below:")
   traceback.print_exc()
```